# Why do both j-- and --j throw exceptions in this LINQ code, but j - 1 does not?

Tags: c#, linq, increment, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm new to C# and practising by writing a solution to the classic 100 doors problem. The below (and probably bad) code solves the problem:

```cs
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var doors = new bool[100];
        var ints = new int[100];
        ints = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).ToArray();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
        {
           ints.Where(j => j % i == 0)
               .Select(j => j)
               .ToList()
               .ForEach(j => doors[j - 1] = !doors[j - 1]); //This is the relevant line.
        }
        Array.ForEach(doors, i => Console.WriteLine(i));
    }
}
```

The line that I've put the comment on has surprised me. It works perfectly fine, but replacing it with either of the below throws `System.IndexOutOfRangeException`

```cs
.ForEach(j => doors[--j] = !doors[--j]);
.ForEach(j => doors[j--] = !doors[j--]);
```

Why are both of these invalid despite `j - 1` being perfectly fine? It's my understanding that, in all circumstances, exactly one of `--j` and `j--` will be equivalent to `j - 1`.

Comment: Important point to clarify before even getting to the Index out of bounds: The increment operator translates to `j = j - 1` either before (`--j`) or after (`j--`) the variable `j` is used within the statement. `j - 1` == `j - 1` the key difference being that there is no assignment to j taking place

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It's my understanding that, in all circumstances, exactly one of --j and j-- will be equivalent to j - 1.

No, definitely not.

The two fail for different reasons though - one when `j` is initially 1, and the other when `j` is initially 100.

First consider this:

```cs
.ForEach(j => doors[--j] = !doors[--j]);
```

That decrements `j` *twice*, and in each case uses the value of `j` *after* the decrement has happened.

The left hand operand is evaluated first, so when `j` is 1, this ends up evaluating array indexes as:

```cs
doors[0] = !doors[-1];
```

Obviously, `doors[-1]` is invalid.

Now let's consider the second option:

```cs
.ForEach(j => doors[j--] = !doors[j--]);
```

This again decrements `j` twice, but in each array indexing operation uses the value of `j` *before* the decrement. So when `j` is 100, this ends up evaluating array indexes as:

```cs
doors[100] = !doors[99];
```

This time it's `doors[100]` which is invalid.

In your *working* code, you're using `j - 1` for both indexes, without modifying `j` at all, so as `j` goes from 1 to 100, the array indexes you're using go from 0 to 99, which are valid.

I would strongly advise against using pre/post-increments/decrements in any expression or statement where you use the modified variable in more than one place - and *definitely* avoid pre/post-increments/decrements of the same variable multiple times in the same expression or statement.